# How to process Iterables.partition(...) results in parallel for use with BatchGetItem API?

Tags: java, java-8, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to call BatchGetItem to retrieve items from DynamoDB. As input we can get a list of up to 1000 keys (or as little as 1 key). These keys coincide with the hashKey for our DynamoDB table.

Since the BatchGetItem API only takes in up to 100 items per call, I am trying to split up the request into batches of only 100 items each, make the calls in parallel, and then merge the results into a single Set again.

For those unfamiliar with the DynamoDB who could still give advice on an extremely stripped down version (1st example) I'd appreciate it! Otherwise, please see the second more accurate example below.

**1st Example - extremely stripped down**

```
public Set<SomeResultType> retrieveSomething(Set<String> someSet) {
   ImmutableSet.Builder<SomeResultType> resultBuilder = ImmutableSet.builder();

   // FIXME - how to parallelize? 
   for (List<Map<String, String>> batch : Iterables.partition(someSet, 100)) {
       result = callSomeLongRunningAPI(batch);
       resultBuilder.addAll(result.getItems());
   }
   return resultBuilder.build();
}
```

**2nd Example - closer to my actual problem -**
Below is a stripped down, dummy version of what I'm currently doing (as such, please forgive formatting / style issues). It currently works and gets all the items, but I can't figure out how to get the batches (see FIXME) to get executed in parallel and end up in a single set. Since performance is pretty important in the system I'm trying to build, any tips would be appreciated in helping this code be more efficient!

```
public Set<SomeResultType> retrieveSomething(Set<String> someIds) {
    if (someIds.isEmpty()) {
        // handle this here
    }

    Collection<Map<String, AttributeValue>> keyAttributes = someIds.stream()
            .map(id -> ImmutableMap.<String, AttributeValue>builder()
                    .put(tableName, new AttributeValue().withS(id)).build())
            .collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList());

    ImmutableSet.Builder<SomeResultType> resultBuilder = ImmutableSet.builder();
    Map<String, KeysAndAttributes> itemsToProcess;
    BatchGetItemResult result;

    // FIXME - make parallel?
    for (List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> batch : Iterables.partition(keyAttributes, 100)) {
        KeysAndAttributes keysAndAttributes = new KeysAndAttributes()
                .withKeys(batch)
                .withAttributesToGet(...// some attribute names);

        itemsToProcess = ImmutableMap.of(tableName, keysAndAttributes);
        result = this.dynamoDB.batchGetItem(itemsToProcess);

        resultBuilder.addAll(extractItemsFromResults(tableName, result));
    }

    return resultBuilder.build());
}
```

Help with either the super stripped down case or the 2nd example would be *greatly* appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it. what is stopping you from creating a ThreadPool, submit your tasks, wait till they are done and glue them to a Set again?

Comment: @Eugene: the fact that I don’t know how to do that, nor did I know that it was safe to do that with a single set?

Comment: well, this is not a coding service site... You got to show something you tried.

Comment: I don't see where I was asking someone to code for me. Are the lines of code I provided above not enough of an attempt at trying? I was asking for advice on how I could try to parallelize my batches. I stripped it down to the base problem I was having and was hoping for ideas and feedback on a clean solution since all I tried so far seemed messy and not thread safe.

Comment: @Eugene Clearly OP isn't asking anyone to code for them, but for advice and showed what they've attempted so far.

Comment: @rhlin888 after re-reading it, I have to agree